# Ghostscript works in php language?

Tags: ghostscript

Do **ghostscript** works in **php** language?
Convert Pdf to Jpg with ghostscript code image in php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ghostscript is generally distributed as a binary executable, if you can execute binaries from PHP then you can use it. The core can also be built as a library which can be dynamically or statically linked, but I doubt you can do that from PHP.